# sequence of functions for which the derivative is bounded converges uniformly?

Tags: uniform-convergence, lipschitz-functions, sequence-of-function

I'd like to prove that for a sequence of differentiables functions $(f_n)$ on $[0;1]$ which converges to $0$, actually converges uniformly.

We only know that $\vert f'_n(x)\vert \leq 2015 + \cos(x) $ for all $x$ and $n$.

I know that it means that the derivatives of all functions from the sequence is bounded by 2016 and thus they are lipschitz, but I don't know if it helps to prove that the convergence is uniform.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed identified the key element of the proof. The other is the compactness of $[0, 1]$.

If you don't want to work it out yourself :

Let $\varepsilon > 0$.
Since $[0, 1]$ is compact, there exists an integer $N$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_N \in [0, 1]$ such that
$$[0, 1] \subset \bigcup_{0 \leq i \leq N} B(x_i, \frac{\varepsilon}{2016}).$$
(no need for big guns here, you can just take $N = \mathrm{floor}(2016/\varepsilon)$ and $x_i = i/N $.
Since $f_n(x_i) \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ for every $0\leq i \leq N$, there exists $n_0 \geqslant 0$ such that
$$\forall n \geq n_0, \forall 0 \leq i \leq N, |f_n(x_i)| \leq \varepsilon. $$
If $y \in [0, 1]$, there exists an index $i_0$ such that $x \in B(x_{i_0}, \frac{\varepsilon}{2016})$. Thus, applying the triangle inequality,
$$ \forall n \geq n_0, \quad |f_n(y)| \leq |f_n(y) - f_n(x_{i_0})| + |f_n(x_{i_0})| \leq 2016\cdot |y - x_{i_0}| + |f_n(x_{i_0})| \leq 2 \varepsilon. $$
Hence, $$\forall n \geq n_0, \|f_n\|_{\infty} \leq 2\varepsilon.$$ The convergence is uniform.